# Rails 3.2.9 accepts_nested_attributes_for confusion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, belongs-to

I have a model Event and a model Serie.
They are defined like this:

```
in event.rb

belongs_to :serie
accepts_nested_attributes_for :serie
attr_accessible :serie

in serie.rb

has_many :events
```

Event table has the serie_id key.

In the event form I have pretty much the following:

```
 form_for @event do |f|
   ...
   ...
   f.fields_for @event.serie do |serie_f|
     ....
   end
 end
```

The request to the controller is coming like this:

```
... "event"=>{...., "serie"=>{"..."=>"19/12/2012", ....}, ...}...
```

In the create action of events_controller I have:

```
def create
  @event = current_user.events.new(params[:event])
  ....
```

In this line I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Serie(#134112340) expected, got ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess(#92663620))
```

Unsure what the problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check this question : [ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch when attempting to save nested attributes in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011022/activerecordassociationtypemismatch-when-attempting-to-save-nested-attributes).
I think that you simply have to replace `attr_accessible :serie` by `attr_accessible :serie_attributes` in your model.
And in your view, try `f.fields_for :serie do |serie_f|` instead of `f.fields_for @event.serie do |serie_f|`